# If velocity for an interval is zero then is acceleration also zero throughout?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

We know that if velocity is zero for an **instant**, then acceleration need not be zero (a simple example of which is a ball thrown upwards.)

> But if velocity is zero for an **interval**, will acceleration also be zero throughout?

I thought it should be true, as the instant $v$ comes to $0$, $a$ should become $0$ to allow the velocity to remain zero throughout that **interval**

**Q.** Is this **true**? How can we show this?

I tried the following:

let $a=kt$ (a is dependent on t)
$$\implies \dfrac{dv}{dt} = kt$$

$$\int^v_{v_0} dv = \int^t_{t_0} kt~dt$$

$$v-v_0 = \dfrac{k(t^2 - t^2_0)}{2}$$

Now if $v_0$ to $v$ be interval when velocity is zero, $k = 0$ implying acceleration is zero ($kt=0$).

**Q.** Is this **correct way** to show this?

Comment: Hi Tim. Do you mean the velocity is zero at all times during the interval, or just that the average velocity is zero over the interval?

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes its zero in the whole interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceleration is the time derivative of the velocity:

$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt} $$

so if the velocity does not change with time the acceleration is necessarily zero. Since in your example the velocity is constant during the interval that means $dv/dt = 0$ and therefore that $a = 0$ during the interval.

The velocity doesn't have to be zero. Any constant non-zero value will also give $a = 0$.

Comment: Yeah if $v = v_0$, then $k = 0$ in my example isnt it?

Comment: Yes, though that seems an unnecessarily complicated way of proving that $a = 0$ when it's zero by definition.

Comment: @JohnRennie Tim's method only covered the constant acceleration case, so it showed that if the acceleration is constant then it must be zero, whereas your method actually shows that acceleration is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here average velocity is zero let time be infinitesimally small then the same average velocity now become instantaneous velocity for the same interval of time. Let  x and x+ dx be the displacement point in interval t to t+dt and hence let v and v+dv be the velocities at those points now instant acceleration = {v+dv} - {v} / dt  which is zero.

Comment: Hi aryen, note that we do have an equation editor built into the site; search `notation` in [help] for details.